# Error 'cannot convert from bool to list<bool> when using checkboxfor in a for loop that is within another for loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I am trying to create a quiz, the quiz has questions that require a single answer and questions that require multiple answers to be selected.  For the questions that require multiple answers to be selected I am using the Checkboxfor helper.  I'll shorten all my code for the sake of the question.  I have a viewmodel which is sent to the page:

```
public class QuizViewModel
{
    public int QuizQuestionID { get; set; }
    public int QuizID { get; set; }
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int OldCoursePageID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
    public IList<QuizAnswers> QuizAnswers { get; set; }


}
```

The model QuizAnswers which is used in the viewModel:

```
public class QuizAnswers
{
    [Key]
    public int QuizAnsID { get; set; }
    public int QuizQuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Correct { get; set; }

    public virtual QuizQuestions QuizQuestions { get; set; }

}
```

In my view I have a loop for the questions and then for the answers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
if (Model[i].Type == 2)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < Model[i].QuizAnswers.Count(); k++)
                {
                    <li>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model[i].QuizAnswers[k].Correct, new { value = false, id = "checkanswer", data_questionid = @Model[i].Order })
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].QuizAnswers[k].Answer)
                    </li>
                }
            }
}
```

I am receiving the error on the checkboxfor helper.  I was planning on creating a field for the boolean returned by the checkbox, however I just tested to see if I could create the helper and populate the already existing Correct boolean field with the checkbox boolean and ran into this problem.

As far as I can see:

```
Model[i].QuizAnswers[k].Correct
```

Should provide a single bool to populate not a list.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `model =>` part of your `Html.CheckBoxFor`. If you add that like you have in your `@Html.DisplayFor` it should take the error away

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, as painfully obvious as it ended up being...

Comment: I'd say a little over 50% of the time, it's something that is blatantly obvious and staring you in the face haha. It happens to us all at some point :)